# WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified in pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnet

I was trying to open telnet connection using pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn on Windows as pexpect.spawn is only available on Linux platform. I have tested the same python script with pexpect.spawn on Linux and it works fine. However, I am unable to open telnet using pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn on Windows. The line `pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn("C:/Windows/System32/telnet.exe <IP> <PORT>")` shows following error

```
    console = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn(mycommand)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pexpect\popen_spawn.py", line 45, in __ini
t__
    self.proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Now telnet.exe is available at the C:/Windows/System32 and I have successfully tested the same command using telnet on command prompt. What am I doing wrong? Any idea? I am using python 2.7

Comment: print os.environ['COMSPEC'] prints as C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe

Answer (score 2):

Pexpect doesn't seem to like the backslashes in paths !!  e.g. try this:

```
mycommand = mycommand.replace("\\", "/")
console = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn(mycommand)
```

(Windows only problem)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an absolute path for your command-execution.
To find out where  telnet resides, run the following in cmd.exe: where  telnet and that should give you the absolute path.

Then simply do:

popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('C:/Windows/System32/telnet ***')

Answer (score 0):

I opened a pull request for `pexpect` that fixes this issue. Until it is accepted, use [demented-hedgehog's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710046/531158).